# How can we make infinite loop with repeating numbers?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I made an array  `int spriteAnimationRight[3] = {0, 136, 272};` and I want these numbers to repeat like following:

```
0  
136  
272  
0  
136  
272  
..  
..
```

How can we do it?

Comment: How do you intend to use it?

Comment: For now just printing it on cmd.
But later on for sprite animation.

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following

```
while(1)
{
   cout<<spriteAnimationRight[0];
   cout<<spriteAnimationRight[1];
   cout<<spriteAnimationRight[2];
}
```

Comment: I like this very much :) Simplest :D

Comment: Do you have experience with SFML?

Comment: No I don't have experience with SFML

Answer (score 3):

Use modulo:

```
int spriteAnimationRight[3] = {0, 136, 272};
for (auto i = 0; ; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", spriteAnimationRight[i%3]);
}
```

Comment: That's fine until the counter overflows and gives undefined behaviour. `i = (i+1)%3` might be a better option.

Comment: It won't overflow because auto i on most compilers becomes unsigned int. when it wraps around it will just wrap back to 0.

Comment: No, `auto` will infer `int` from the type of `0`. Even if it were unsigned, you'll get the wrong value (modulo 3) when it wraps to zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i=0;
while(1)
{
    DoSomething(spriteAnimationRight[i]);
    i++;
    if(i >= 3) i = 0;
}
```

Comment: But then it has to hit 3 exactly. Of course, in this small example it obviously does. But there can be situations where the loop is more complex with more lines which might modify `i`. Or situations where `i` is not an integer but a double and you want to reset it when it hits a border (or course then it wouldn't be used as an array index). So I prefer `>=` because it's more robust in more complex scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [modulo](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/) operator:

```
int i = 0;
while(1) {
   if(i == 3) i = 0;  //preventing overflow
   cout<<spriteAnimationRight[i % 3];
   i++;
}
```

Why this works?

The modulo operator finds the remainder of division of one number by another<sup>1</sup>.

```
0 % 3  → 0
1 % 3  → 1
2 % 3  → 2
0 % 3  → 0
1 % 3  → 1
2 % 3  → 2
..
..
```

<sup>1</sup> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: When it returns to 0 we may skip one of the three things we need though.

Comment: @Henrik No. `i` will not be 3 as I'm setting it to 0 if it's 3. Can you explain more why do you think I'll have this?..

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun after you use it you set 3 to 0, but you use mod, so you will have 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2,...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int index=0;
    int spriteAnimationRight[3] = {0, 136, 272};
    while(1)
    {
         if(index==3)
         {/*when index=3, resset it to first index*/
          index=0;
         }
          cout<<spriteAnimationRight[index]<<endl; 
          index++;    
    }
}
```

And if you want to see output clearly then you need to create some delay in each output, for that purpose you can make a function delay like this.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void delay()//to see output clearly you can make a sleep function
{
 /*this fucntion uses empty for loops to create delay*/
     for(int i=0;i<7000;i++)
     {
          for(int j=0;j<7000;j++)
          {
          }
     }
}

int main()
{
    int index=0;
    int spriteAnimationRight[3] = {0, 136, 272};
    while(1)
    {
         if(index==3)
         {/*when index=3, resset it to first index*/
          index=0;
         }
          cout<<spriteAnimationRight[index]<<endl; 
          index++; 
          delay();//for creating delay
    }
}
```